# FileNotFoundException while accessing webpage

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception, urlconnection

I am trying to get the title of youtube video by using it video Id with the help of API web page. But, I am facing `FileNotFoundException` while trying to access the same through code.

My code is as follows,

```
 String title = "";
        try {
            URL u = new URL("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" + videoID + "?v=2");
            URLConnection uc = u.openConnection();
            System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");
            uc.setRequestProperty("Host", "www.youtube.com");
            uc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
            uc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.112 Safari/535.1");
            uc.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
            uc.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "html");
            uc.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");

            System.out.println("Retrieving video title for \"" + videoID + "\"");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream()));
            String tmp = "";

            String pageResponse = "";
            while ((tmp = br.readLine()) != null) {
                pageResponse += tmp;
            }

            title = parseResponse(pageResponse, "<media:title type='plain'>", "</media:title>");//pageResponse is a method to extract the text between 2 stings
            System.out.println("Title : " + title);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);

        }
```

Console output :

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m7dapUWHykw
Video ID : m7dapUWHykw
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/m7dapUWHykw?v=2
Retrieving video title for "m7dapUWHykw"
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/m7dapUWHykw?v=2
```

**But If i open the same using web browser, I am able to access it without any issue.**

Can anybody tell me what is wrong with the code ?

PrintStackTrace of the above method is as follows,

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/m7dapUWHykw?v=2
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1311)
        at getytv.YouTubeDownloader.getYouTubeVideoTitle(YouTubeDownloader.java:170)
        at getytv.YouTubeDownloader.getYouTubeVideoDownloadLinks(YouTubeDownloader.java:276)
        at getytv.GetYouTubeVideo.updateDownloadTable(GetYouTubeVideo.java:215)
        at getytv.ClipBoardMonitor$1.run(ClipBoardMonitor.java:88)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of doing `System.out.println(e);`, can you do `e.printStackTrace()` and add the results of that to your question?

Comment: I tried your code it works fine
check if your using proxy, you have to specify the proxy parameters if your using proxy

Comment: @mthmulders : Added the printStackTrace()

Comment: I am using Windows 7 machine. IF I run this with windows, it is working. I am also accessing a Linux machine through VNC and if I run this code, inside the linux machine, I am getting this error.

Comment: Try to use [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_java) which can fetch video feeds, comments, responses, and playlists

Comment: Thanks aymankoo :) I have added the proxy port and hostname using   System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "myhostname") and      System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080") respectively. Now it is working fine. :)